# Django: how to add a non-database object to query results

Tags: python, django

Let's consider a situation where I have a bunch of people who own some shirts:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Shirt(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I take portrait photos of them in one of their shirts:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    shirt = models.ForeignKey(Shirt)
```

In templates I use stuff like

```
{{ the_photo.shirt.description }}
```

and

```
{% for shirt in the_person.shirt_set.all %}
    {{ shirt.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

I also have forms to let me pick a shirt for a photo from the model's inventory.

Now, a twist! I can also take a photo of them without a shirt! So I want `the_person.shirt_set` to contain also a `description='topless'` entry in additional to any shirts they might own. I'd rather not store an additional `'topless'` shirt for each person and wouldn't like to have to modify each form and list to add this option.

I had an idea of creating a `Topless` class:

```
class Topless(Shirt):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Topless, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.description = 'Topless'
```

and adding it to lists:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    def shirts(self):
        l = list(Shirt.objects.filter(owner=self))
        l.insert(0, Topless())
        return l
```

(and switching from `the_person.shirt_set` to `the_person.shirts` in templates of course), but it's getting ugly with `the_photo.shirt` since the id is None (or 0) and it looks like it will require a bunch of ugly hacks to accommodate for that.

But maybe I'm doing it wrong? Any ideas? What's the most elegant and pythonic way to do it?

Comment: You might want to look at how the Django auth module handles Users - particularly [the `auth.models.AnonymousUser` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) to do something similar to what you want to do.

Comment: @Mike: using a "special" shirt that is not really a shirt, seems more like a hack, unnatural. Adding handling for shirt=None may be extra work, but you'd have something logical and natural.

Comment: I agree - even if you say it out loud, setting shirt = None reads like you would expect it to

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks a lot!